# How to count instances of something within a implicit data structure?

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I have a CSV that has a "Purchase Count" of items sold in a video game. Each purchase has a username and gender (and other things). Because it counts each "Purchase" and the same username can show up for multiple purchases. I was able to count total number of distinct users using the `.nunique` function that gets rid of the same name being counted multiple times in "Total Users". The gender "Male, Female, Other" shows up for every purchase and user.

How do I count the number of each gender based on the total (distinct) users rather than the total purchases?

Comment: We need to see a snippet of the CSV and your code attempt. Sounds like you want to get a count by gender of unique users who made at least one purchase.

Comment: can you share some example dataframe and desired output

Comment: one thing you can do is `df.groupby(['username', 'gender']).size().reset_index()`